# Can I use the .click function to switch user tabs in WhatsApp Web?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, click, whatsapp

I'm trying to write a google chrome console script for WhatsApp Web which logs user's online statuses for later analyzation. I managed to define a function, which extracts the online status from the innerHTML, however this works just for one person at a time (since only this person's HTML is active and loaded). I had the idea for the script to switch through the user tabs (at the left of the page) and each time check the innerHTML for the online status. I tried the .click function, but couldn't figure out what to define as a click target... Maybe there is an even better way to solve this?  Many thanks.  [1: click on contact 2: check status 3: click on next contact 4: check status etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wBR5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to click one by one. There are scripts like [LoranKloeze](https://github.com/LoranKloeze/WhatsAllApp) and *others* on *github* doing that for you using timed functions. If you even have little javascript experince, you can understand the code and change it to your needs.

Comment: Okay, then I‘ll try it that way. Thanks for the response!

Comment: So I tried it with Loran's script, but it only receives online status information for around 5 minutes, then it doesn't output anymore. Do you think the click through version will not work at all?

Comment: It's about whatsappweb's new version has changed some and online status is only available if you have a chat history with the contact OR if they have you in their contact list.

Comment: Also after that 5 minutes, if you click contacts on Android app, you continue to receive updates in Web. If you can code for Android that clicks contacts in Android app for you, can get updates for a long time in Web

Comment: Oka, that clears things up. Thanks for your answer and time!